# Returning a List<> inheritance C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list

```
class cuentaBancaria
{
    public cuentaBancaria()
    {

    }
    public cuentaBancaria(string nombreCliente, string numCuenta, double tipoInteres, double saldo)
    {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        this.numCuenta = numCuenta;
        this.tipoInteres = tipoInteres;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
    public string nombreCliente { get; set; }
    public string numCuenta { get; set; }
    public double tipoInteres { get; set; }
    public double saldo { get; set; }

    public static List<cuentaBancaria> cuentas = new List<cuentaBancaria>()
    {
        new cuentaBancaria ("John Doe", "123456", 1.5, 159),
        new Tarjeta ("John Doe", "123456" , 1.5, 159, "123456789012", "John Doe", TipoTarjeta.CREDITO)
     };
}
```

TipoTarjeta:

```
enum TipoTarjeta
{
    CREDITO,
    DEBITO,
    MONEDERO,
    FINANCIACION
}
```

Tarjeta:

```
class Tarjeta : cuentaBancaria
{
    public Tarjeta()
    {

    }
    public Tarjeta(string nombreCliente, string numCuenta, double tipoInteres, double saldo, string numTarjeta, string nombre, TipoTarjeta tipoTarjeta)
    {
        base.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        base.numCuenta = numCuenta;
        base.tipoInteres = tipoInteres;
        base.saldo = saldo;
        this.numTarjeta = numTarjeta;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tipoTarjeta = tipoTarjeta;
    }
    public string numTarjeta { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public TipoTarjeta tipoTarjeta { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return the elements that has a TipoTarjeta.XXX but when I try the

```
cuentas.Where(c => c.tipoTarjeta == tipo)
```

I get the error that is an element of the child (Tarjeta) not cuentaBancaria.

How can I only get those elements with that type?

Comment: Show us the code for `cuentaBancaria`.

Comment: and for `Tarjeta`.

Comment: You need to check ' => c is Tarjeta && c.tipoTarjeta == tipo '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type mismatch.

Your function is declared such that it returns `List<cuentaBancaria>`, but `Where` is a LINQ extension method that returns an `IEnumerable<cuentBancaria>`.

To resolve your issue, add a call to the `ToList()` extension method as follows:

`cuentas.Where(c => c.tipoTarjeta == tipo).ToList()`

**UPDATE**

I copied your code to VSCode and this version of Main works for me. From what I could tell, you needed to reference `cuentas` through `cuentaBancaria`; also, the property you were referencing in the `Where` clause was incorrect, based on the class definition.

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
      var tipo = 3.15;
      var result = cuentaBancaria.cuentas.Where(c => c.tipoInteres == tipo).ToList();
      foreach (var item in result)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item.tipoInteres);
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I do add that it says that is not defined in cuentaBancaria and to fix it it recommends to add internal TipoTarjeta tipoTarjeta; (cuentaBancaria)

Comment: Can you show the full method where you are making the call to cuentas.Where?

Comment: I'm calling it from the mainWindow is a WPF there's a combobox which you select the type and I just do that call cuentas.Where(c => c.tipoTarjeta == tipo)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to filter the list to only the types of `Tarjeta`, and then you can filter by properties of `Tarjeta`. You can do this using [`.OfType<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) in LINQ:

```
cuentas.OfType<Tarjeta>().Where(c => c.tipoTarjeta == tipo)
```